# Dice Statistics

Tags: python, probability, dice

I wanted to build a dice Stats Simulator in Python. The idea is that you have a starting array, containing [1,...,1] for the lowest possible dice rolls, a one. I already have one example for 4d4 and this works so I want my code to do it for every combination. So I wrote Variables and Functions, for recursive use. But it gives me an output, which is not right and much too high. Maybe somebody can help me and if you need explanation, then you can ask.

```
sides = 4
rolls = 4
constant = sides**rolls
beginningtable = []

for i in range(rolls):
    beginningtable.append(1)


values = {rolls : 0}
check = True

print("-------------")

def checking(valuetable):
    print(valuetable)
    sum = 0

    checker = 0
    for i in valuetable:
        sum = sum + i

    for i in values.keys():
        if sum == i:
            values[i] = values [i] + 1
            checker = 1

    if checker == 0:
        values[sum] = 1



def gothroughindex(table, index):

    checking(table)

    for i in range(sides-1):
        table[index] += 1
        checking(table)

    return table

def loop(looptable, loopcounter):
    for i in range(loopcounter):
        if i != (loopcounter-1):
            looptable[i] = 1
        else:
            looptable[i] += 1
    return looptable

def recursiveloop(table,counter, loopvalue):



    if counter == rolls:
        for i in range(rolls):
            print("\ncounter == counter\n")
            recursiveloop(table, counter-1, loopvalue-1)
            table = loop(table, loopvalue)
    elif counter == 1:
        for i in range(rolls-1):
            print("\ncounter == 1\n")
            print(loopvalue)
            gothroughindex(table, 0)
            table = loop(table, loopvalue+1)
    else:
        for i in range(rolls):
            print("\nelse\n")
            print(str(loopvalue) + " here I am")

            recursiveloop(table, counter-1, loopvalue-1)

            gothroughindex(table, 0)
            table = loop(table, loopvalue)



def mainthing(maintable):
    counter = rolls
    loopvalue = rolls
    recursiveloop(maintable, counter, loopvalue)



"""
    for i in range(rolls): #Das sind die ersten vier
        for i in range(rolls): #Das sind die ersten drei
            for i in range(rolls-1): #Das sind die ersten beiden
                gothroughindex(maintable, 0)
                maintable = loop(maintable, 2)    
            gothroughindex(maintable, 0)
            maintable = loop(maintable, 3)
        maintable = loop(maintable, 4)
    """

    print("---------")
    print(maintable)
    print(values)

    sum = 0
    for i in values.keys():
        sum = values[i] + sum
    print(sum)

mainthing(beginningtable)
```

Comment: I for one dont understand your question .... isnt the lowest possible roll always all 1's?

Comment: @JoranBeasley My algorithm wants to calculate every possible combination of dice rolls and you start with the combination of only ones yeah, e.g. 2d3 --> [1,1] --> [2,1] --> [3,1] --> [1,2] --> [2,2] --> [3,2] --> [1,3] --> [2,3] --> [3,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldnt you just simplyfiy all this and use itertools product method to generate these?

generate a range for the number of sides of the dice, and then use that as the iterator for product to pick from. specify the number of dice as the repeat so that product will generate that many items

you can read more on itertools here https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

> itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)
> Cartesian product of input
> iterables.
>
> To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number
> of repetitions with the optional repeat keyword argument. For example,
> product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A).

```py
from itertools import product


def roll_combos(num_dice, num_sides):
    return product(range(1, num_sides + 1), repeat=num_dice)


print(list(roll_combos(2, 3)))
print(list(roll_combos(4, 4)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 1, 2, 4), (1, 1, 3, 1), (1, 1, 3, 2), (1, 1, 3, 3), (1, 1, 3, 4), (1, 1, 4, 1), (1, 1, 4, 2), (1, 1, 4, 3), (1, 1, 4, 4), (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1, 4), (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2, 4), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 1), (1, 2, 4, 2), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 2, 4, 4), (1, 3, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1, 2), (1, 3, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1, 4), (1, 3, 2, 1), (1, 3, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 3, 1), (1, 3, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3, 3), (1, 3, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4, 1), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 3, 4, 3), (1, 3, 4, 4), (1, 4, 1, 1), (1, 4, 1, 2), (1, 4, 1, 3), (1, 4, 1, 4), (1, 4, 2, 1), (1, 4, 2, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 2, 4), (1, 4, 3, 1), (1, 4, 3, 2), (1, 4, 3, 3), (1, 4, 3, 4), (1, 4, 4, 1), (1, 4, 4, 2), (1, 4, 4, 3), (1, 4, 4, 4), (2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 1, 4), (2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 1), (2, 1, 4, 2), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 1, 4, 4), (2, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2, 4), (2, 2, 3, 1), (2, 2, 3, 2), (2, 2, 3, 3), (2, 2, 3, 4), (2, 2, 4, 1), (2, 2, 4, 2), (2, 2, 4, 3), (2, 2, 4, 4), (2, 3, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2, 4), (2, 3, 3, 1), (2, 3, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3, 3), (2, 3, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 3, 4, 2), (2, 3, 4, 3), (2, 3, 4, 4), (2, 4, 1, 1), (2, 4, 1, 2), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 1, 4), (2, 4, 2, 1), (2, 4, 2, 2), (2, 4, 2, 3), (2, 4, 2, 4), (2, 4, 3, 1), (2, 4, 3, 2), (2, 4, 3, 3), (2, 4, 3, 4), (2, 4, 4, 1), (2, 4, 4, 2), (2, 4, 4, 3), (2, 4, 4, 4), (3, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 1, 3), (3, 1, 1, 4), (3, 1, 2, 1), (3, 1, 2, 2), (3, 1, 2, 3), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 3, 3), (3, 1, 3, 4), (3, 1, 4, 1), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 1, 4, 3), (3, 1, 4, 4), (3, 2, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 2, 3), (3, 2, 2, 4), (3, 2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 3, 2), (3, 2, 3, 3), (3, 2, 3, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 2, 4, 2), (3, 2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 4, 4), (3, 3, 1, 1), (3, 3, 1, 2), (3, 3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 1, 4), (3, 3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 2, 4), (3, 3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3, 4), (3, 3, 4, 1), (3, 3, 4, 2), (3, 3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4, 4), (3, 4, 1, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 1, 3), (3, 4, 1, 4), (3, 4, 2, 1), (3, 4, 2, 2), (3, 4, 2, 3), (3, 4, 2, 4), (3, 4, 3, 1), (3, 4, 3, 2), (3, 4, 3, 3), (3, 4, 3, 4), (3, 4, 4, 1), (3, 4, 4, 2), (3, 4, 4, 3), (3, 4, 4, 4), (4, 1, 1, 1), (4, 1, 1, 2), (4, 1, 1, 3), (4, 1, 1, 4), (4, 1, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 2), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 2, 4), (4, 1, 3, 1), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 1, 3, 3), (4, 1, 3, 4), (4, 1, 4, 1), (4, 1, 4, 2), (4, 1, 4, 3), (4, 1, 4, 4), (4, 2, 1, 1), (4, 2, 1, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 1, 4), (4, 2, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2, 2), (4, 2, 2, 3), (4, 2, 2, 4), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 2, 3, 2), (4, 2, 3, 3), (4, 2, 3, 4), (4, 2, 4, 1), (4, 2, 4, 2), (4, 2, 4, 3), (4, 2, 4, 4), (4, 3, 1, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 1, 3), (4, 3, 1, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1), (4, 3, 2, 2), (4, 3, 2, 3), (4, 3, 2, 4), (4, 3, 3, 1), (4, 3, 3, 2), (4, 3, 3, 3), (4, 3, 3, 4), (4, 3, 4, 1), (4, 3, 4, 2), (4, 3, 4, 3), (4, 3, 4, 4), (4, 4, 1, 1), (4, 4, 1, 2), (4, 4, 1, 3), (4, 4, 1, 4), (4, 4, 2, 1), (4, 4, 2, 2), (4, 4, 2, 3), (4, 4, 2, 4), (4, 4, 3, 1), (4, 4, 3, 2), (4, 4, 3, 3), (4, 4, 3, 4), (4, 4, 4, 1), (4, 4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4, 4)]
```

Comment: Oh I did not knew, that there is such a bib in python...thanks a lot.

Comment: But could you maybe clarify how your code works?

Comment: You can read all about the product method from itertools here https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product.  I will update the answer with a brief explantion

Comment: Yeah I already read through it, sorry I was not clear enough. 
For the example 4d4 dices.
First: If I understand it right, you define a tuple at product(range(1,...)) with the range 1,5 here, but this does not make any sense for me here, because a 4 sided dice cannot have the number 5.
Second: I did not really catch up the meaning of the repeating variable. I tested it a bit and if I take repeat = 2, I got tuples with [1,1] [1,2] etc.. and repeat = 3 [1,1,1] [1,1,2] so this repeat variable describes how many total numbers are in my tupel?

Comment: you can look up the range function too from the docs. range will generate you a list of numbers from a start number to an end number but does not include the end number. So range(1, 5) will generate the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4. As 5 is the number to stop at (i.e not included). Now in the example of 2d4 for example. We are using the 4 to generate the numbers a d4 could have, then we use repeat to say we have 2 dice so we need to pick 2 numbers each time.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense now thanks for the explanation!
I would upvote your comment, but I am new here...

Comment: Next step: if you want to know how many possibilities you have of getting each different sum, `collections.Counter` as in `c=Counter([t[0]+t[1] for t in list(roll_combos(4, 4))])` will make the trick. For instance, with 4d4 you have 1 possibilities to total 4, 4 possibilities to total 5, 10 to total 6, etc